# How to prove that $(z^{-1})^{-1} = z$ and $(zw)^{-1} = z^{-1}w^{-1}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I need to prove that $(z^{-1})^{-1} = z$ and $(zw)^{-1} = z^{-1}w^{-1}$ but the only thing I can think about is to consider

$$z = a+bi, w = c+di$$

and then prove it algebraically using laws of multiplication for complex numbers. Any ideas to prove it structuraly?

Comment: What do you mean by structurally?

Comment: @Ahmed just considering the number $z$ and not its algebraic form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\},\cdot$ is a group. Hence the inverse of an element is unique. Since $zz^{-1}=1=z^{-1}z$, we conclude that $z$ is the inverse of $z^{-1}$, this element is denoted by $(z^{-1})^{-1}$. Hence $(z^{-1})^{-1}=z$.

In the same fashion we can conclude that $(zw)^{-1}=w^{-1}z^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z'=z^{-1}$. Then $zz'=1$. But this means that $z=(z')^{-1}$.

Let $w'=w^{-1}$. Then $1=1\cdot1=(zz')(ww')=(zw)(z'w')$. But this means that $(zw)^{-1}=z'w'$.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, $(z^a)^b=z^{ab}$, so $(z^{-1})^{-1}=z$.

We have $(zw)(zw)^{-1}=1.$ Pre-multiply by $z^{-1}$ and then $w^{-1}$ to get the result.